# Get route in Google Maps from current location to destination Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I get one address from database. Then when user click button Map, it will show Google Maps / map from current location user to that destination.

Can you help me?

Comment: Check this one http://codingwitharun.blogspot.in/2016/09/draw-line-between-two-point-using.html

Comment: Thanks .. Any other also can share ..

Comment: are you looking for google map then I can help you. I am also doing the same task for my app

Comment: MapKit or google map is better ? and which one is ease to understand?